# C# Project what to put in Source control (Bitbucket)

Tags: c#, version-control, repository, bitbucket

I have created a C# project. I have created a Bitbucket account and want to put my project there.
What all should I put in the repository and what not to.
I am guess Debug and Release folders should not be uploaded. What about..
- Name/bin/Debug
- Name/obj/Debug
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to start with an established `.gitignore` file.  GitHub has a project that maintains `.gitignore` files for various environments, including Visual Studio.

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Scroll down and grab `VisualStudio.gitignore`.  Or you can download the file with this PowerShell command (set the current directory to the root of the repo, first):

```
(Invoke-WebRequest 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/VisualStudio.gitignore').Content > .gitignore
```

This should give you an idea of what the general consensus is on what belongs in source control and what doesn't in a Visual Studio solution.  In particular, this will exclude the `bin` and `obj` folders so you don't commit outputs to the repository, as well as the `.vs` folder and `*.user` files, which are user-specific data.  It also excludes files and folders used by popular third-party extensions that maintain their own user-specific data.

Once you have a good `.gitignore` file, you can use `git add --all` and it will add everything that's not ignored to the index.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in bin or obj should need to be committed. You'll also need csproj files and nuget package config files (be they xml or json). Things like appconfig files, and .vscode are up to you whether you want to have them in source control.